# Visual Studio surround with current line if nothing selected

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm using the `Surround With` feature in Visual Studio with some custom code snippets. Is there a way to configure visual studio (or a custom surround snippet) to treat the entire line like it is selected, if there is currently no selection?

The same functionality is provided when you do a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> etc. If you have no selected text, it performs the action on the entire line.

Comment: You tagged your question with *resharper*. So I guess you already know that ReSharper's *Sourround Templates* can that auto-line-select.

Comment: no, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone still wants to answer this as far as doing this with Visual Studio's native functions, they can - However it was pointed out to me in a comment that resharper does this automatically. Which is something I did not realize. Seem's I'll be moving all my VisualStudio surround snippets over to Resharper Surround templates!